# What time format is xx:xx.x?

Tags: sql, database, date, time, format

What time format is xx:xx.x ?

From what I'm seeing from sample values

(ranges from 00 to 59):(ranges from 00 to 59):(ranges from 0 to 9)

First two I can guess are either minutes or seconds, I had to guess....

Answer (score 0):

There is no standardized time format that looks like that. However, my best guess is

`minute:second`, where second is measured to one decimal place

Answer (score 0):

```
interval minute to second(1)
```

According to ANSI/ISO SQL.

```
SQL>create table ts (c1 interval minute to second(1));
SQL>insert into ts values (interval '12:34.5' minute to second);
SQL>select * from ts;
c1
========
12:34.5

                  1 row found
```